# How to show content of NSData in bits?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdata, bit

I have NSData and I need to view its content in pure bits. Tried NSLog [NSData description] but it returns NSString. Any suggestions?

Comment: what do you mean by `show`? For debugging purposes or show it in a view in your app. Like in a hex editor for iOS?

Comment: bytes or bits please clarify your question???? well for bytes I have posted the answer

Comment: Why do you need to see bits?  Hex bytes (which any programmer should intuitively know how to interpret) should be perfectly sufficient for most purposes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use this for bytes

```
const char *byte = [data bytes];
NSLog(@"%s",byte);
```

this is for bits

```
const char *byte = [data bytes];
unsigned int length = [data length];
for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
    char n = byte[i];
    char buffer[9];
    buffer[8] = 0; //for null
    int j = 8;
    while(j > 0)
    {
        if(n & 0x01)
        {
            buffer[--j] = '1';
        } else
        {
            buffer[--j] = '0';
        }
        n >>= 1;
    }
    printf("%s ",buffer);
```

Comment: Hm, I see some weird character, not bits, in console when I try with you solution.

Comment: that's why i told you to change your question... it is bytes not bits...`I have NSData and I need to view its content in pure bytes` it was your line anyways will send your the updated code.till then correct your question..

Answer (score 3):

You can look at these bytes in memory browser window:

```
void* bytes_memory = [yourData bytes];  // set breakpoint after this line
```

... after stopping on breakpoint find `bytes_memory` in Local variables window, right click on it and choose `View memory of *bytes_memory`.

If you want to print to console bits (in format 10011100), then you will need to convert data into corresponding string representation ([here](http://www.digitalpeer.com/id/print) is example).